# Why doesn't Environment.NewLine work when converting between byte array and string

Tags: c#, string, sockets, type-conversion

I'm sending data between a server and a client using TCP. I send a stream of bytes, so I convert the strings to byte arrays, send to the client, then convert it back to a string. Then I insert this string into a multiline textbox with `Environment.NewLine` after each one. However, a new line isn't appearing.

I've tried multiple ways of converting the string to arrays and back to strings all with the same result. `Environment.NewLine` doesn't work. `\n\r` doesn't work.

I've tried converting using the following techniques:

1. `Encoding.ASCII.GetString()` and `Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes()`
2. `Encoding.Unicode.GetString()` and `Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes()`
3. I've also used the code on the following website which uses:

   `System.Text.UTF8Encoding  encoding=new System.Text.UTF8Encoding();`

   [String to Byte Array Conversion in C# and VB.NET (and back)](http://www.chilkatsoft.com/faq/dotnetstrtobytes.html)

How should I convert these strings back and forth to get this to work? My client is currently C# but is going to be java in production.

EDIT:

```
    AttachMessage(ByteArrayToStr(messageInByteArray)); // Doesn't work
    AttachMessage("TEST"); // works


    public void AttachMessage(string data)
    {
        textBox2.Text += data + Environment.NewLine;
    }

    public static string ByteArrayToStr(byte[] arr)
    {
        System.Text.UTF8Encoding encoding = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding();
        return encoding.GetString(arr);
    }

    public static byte[] StrToByteArray(string str)
    {
        System.Text.UTF8Encoding encoding = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding();
        return encoding.GetBytes(str);
    }
```

It is a conversion issue because it works with non-converted strings.

EDIT 2:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public volatile List<TcpClient> connectedClients;
    public volatile bool ServerOn;
    public volatile TcpListener server;
    public delegate void txtBoxDelegate(string data);
    public delegate void tcpCommand(string ipAddress);
    public delegate void chatMessageDelegate(byte[] message);

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        connectedClients = new List<TcpClient>();
        ServerOn = false;
        server = new TcpListener(System.Net.IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 6789);
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!ServerOn)
        {
            Thread serverThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(TcpServer));
            serverThread.IsBackground = true;
            serverThread.Start();
            lblServerStatus.Text = "The server is On.";
            lblServerStatus.ForeColor = Color.Green;
            lstServerUpdates.Text = String.Empty;
            button1.Text = "Turn server Off";
            ServerOn = true;
        }
        else
        {
            ServerOn = false;
            lstServerUpdates.Text = "Server has been turned off.";
            lblServerStatus.Text = "The server is Off.";
            lblServerStatus.ForeColor = Color.Red;
        }
    }

    public static string ByteArrayToStr(byte[] arr)
    {
        System.Text.UTF8Encoding encoding = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding();
        return encoding.GetString(arr);
    }

    public static byte[] StrToByteArray(string str)
    {
        System.Text.UTF8Encoding encoding = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding();
        return encoding.GetBytes(str);
    }

    private void TcpServer()
    {
        printToTextBox("Starting TCP Server.");

        server.Start();
        while (ServerOn)
        {
            if (!server.Pending())
            {
                Thread.Sleep(10);
                continue;
            }
            TcpClient clientSocket = server.AcceptTcpClient();

            NetworkStream stream = clientSocket.GetStream();

            connectedClients.Add(clientSocket);

            Thread clientThread = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(ClientThreads));
            clientThread.Start(clientSocket);

            byte[] bytes = StrToByteArray("Successfully connected to the server.");

            stream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
            printToTextBox("Client successfully connected to server.");
        }


        server.Stop();
    }

    public void ClientThreads(object tcpClient)
    {
        TcpClient clientSocket = (TcpClient)tcpClient;
        NetworkStream clientStream = clientSocket.GetStream();

        byte[] clientMessage = new byte[100];

        while (ServerOn)
        {
            clientStream.Read(clientMessage, 0, clientMessage.Length);
            string message = ByteArrayToStr(clientMessage);
            if (message.Contains("!chat"))
            {
                SendChatMessage(StrToByteArray(message.Substring(5) + Environment.NewLine));
            }
            else if (message.Contains("!start")) 
            {
                StartWebcam(((IPEndPoint)clientSocket.Client.RemoteEndPoint).Address.ToString());
            }
            else if (message.Contains("!stop"))
            {
                StopWebcam(((IPEndPoint)clientSocket.Client.RemoteEndPoint).Address.ToString());
            }
        }
        clientSocket.Close();
        connectedClients.Clear();
    }

    public void printToTextBox(string data)
    {
        if (this.InvokeRequired)
        {
            this.BeginInvoke(new txtBoxDelegate(printToTextBox), data);
            return;
        }
        lstServerUpdates.Text += data + Environment.NewLine;
    }

    public void SendChatMessage(byte[] message)
    {
        foreach (TcpClient client in connectedClients)
        {
            NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();
            stream.Write(message, 0, message.Length);
            printToTextBox(ByteArrayToStr(message));
        }
    }

    public void StartWebcam(string IPAddress)
    {
        if (this.InvokeRequired)
        {
            this.BeginInvoke(new tcpCommand(StartWebcam), IPAddress);
            return;
        }

        //code to stop webcam for the specified client
        printToTextBox("Starting webcam for IP: " + IPAddress);
    }

    public void StopWebcam(string IPAddress)
    {
        if (this.InvokeRequired)
        {
            this.BeginInvoke(new tcpCommand(StopWebcam), IPAddress);
            return;
        }

        //code to stop webcam for specified client
        printToTextBox("Stopping webcam for IP: " + IPAddress);
    }
}
```

Comment: The code. Post it. Sounds like a problem with your UI code, not an encoding issue.

Comment: Still not that clear... this is what, Windows Forms? ASP.NET? Are you seeing everything appended on *one* line, or are you seeing just one newline and expecting two? Are you sure the textbox is actually configured as multiline? Can you post the code that *does* work for you, and/or can we see the actual output? What if you create a byte array by using `Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes`? The `Environment.NewLine` is not even inside any of the encoding calls, so that really can't be the problem.

Comment: You're right, I tested it in a separate application and its adding new lines as it should, let me debug a bit more and I'll get back to you if I still can't figure it out. I was focusing on the wrong thing while debugging before

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I send a stream of bytes

That's correct, TCP is a stream.  Which doesn't support anything like a "packet".  Like a line of text.  There's no obvious way to convert a stream to byte[], other than to receive *everything* until the client closes the connection.  Which of course means that you'll display *everything*, followed by a **single** Environment.NewLine.

Rethink your approach.  Like actually sending the line-endings in the data as well so you don't have to add them in the receiver.  Artificially creating packets by first sending 4 bytes that encodes the packet length is another approach.

Comment: This makes sense! However, I think my approach is completely wrong. I've attached the whole server to the post. Could you please take a look and give any advice on how I could make this work better? (Its for a school project, so not many people will be using it)

Comment: It is exactly like I described.  SendChatMessage tries to put packets in a stream with no way for the receiver to convert the stream back to packets.  Send the byte[] length first so the receiver knows how many bytes to read.

Comment: Then I use that to create the buffer size? Once I have the byte size on the server, then how to I tell it to only read that many bytes?